# How can I fix the "discount" badge showing on top of everything on my website? I'm using Acowebs Product Labels For Woocommerce 1.1.8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, xhtml

If I scroll on my webpage (tencuialamecaniatatraditionala.ro) the discount
badge is always on top of everything, even on top of the header, which I hate... Please help!

A screenshot with the problem
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Ethan! I sent an image link with my problem in the description of my question, I think that if you open that up you can easily understand what I am asking for... With the addition of the title and description of course!

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that still face this problem:

Change the z-index value eg.

```
.element-you-want-to-change {
    z-index: 0;
 }
```